# R: new column based whether categorical levels of another column are the same or different from each other

Tags: r

I am having a problem creating a new column in a data where the column content is defined by levels in a factor in a different column are the same or different, which is dependent on another 2 columns.

Basically, I have a bunch of cows with different ID's that can have different parities. The quarter is the udder quarter affected by the disease and I would like to create a new column with a result that is based on whether quarters are the same or different or occurring once. Any help would be appreciated. Code for abbreviated data frame below/ The new column is the one I would like to achieve.

```
AnimalID <- c(10,10,10,10,12,12,12,12,14)
Parity <- c(8,8,9,9,4,4,4,4,2)
Udder_quarter <- c("LH","LH","RH","RH","LH","RH","LF","RF","RF")
new_column <- c("same quarter","same quarter","different quarter","different quarter","different quarter","different quarter","different quarter","different quarter","one quarter")
quarters<- data.frame(AnimalID,Parity,Udder_quarter,new_column) 

structure(list(HerdAnimalID = c(100165, 100165, 100327, 100327, 
100450, 100450), Parity = c(6, 6, 5, 5, 3, 3), no_parities = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), case = c("1pathogen_lact", "1pathogen_lact", 
"1pathogen_lact", "1pathogen_lact", "1pathogen_lact", "1pathogen_lact"
), FARM = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `CASE NO` = c("101", "101", "638", 
"638", "593", "593"), MASTDATE = structure(c(1085529600, 1087689600, 
1097884800, 1101254400, 1106092800, 1106784000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), QRT = c("LF", "LF", "RH", "LF", "LH", 
"LH"), MastitisDiagnosis = c("Corynebacterium spp", "Corynebacterium spp", 
"S. uberis", "S. uberis", "Bacillus spp", "Bacillus spp"), PrevCalvDate = 
structure(c(1075334400, 
1075334400, 1096156800, 1096156800, 1091145600, 1091145600), class = 
c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), .Names = c("HerdAnimalID", "Parity", 
"no_parities", "case", "FARM", "CASE NO", "MASTDATE", "QRT", 
"MastitisDiagnosis", "PrevCalvDate"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = 
c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I have difficulties understanding how the new column is calculated. Could you please elaborate? Why are rows 3 and 4 labeled 'different quarter'?

Comment: Apologies, rows 3 and 4 should be saying same quarter as they are bith RH within the same parity.

Comment: The new column is the one I am trying to get to, I just entered it manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

quarters %>%
  group_by(AnimalID) %>%
  mutate(new_column = ifelse(n()==1, 'one quarter', NA)) %>%
  group_by(Parity, add=T) %>%
  mutate(new_column=ifelse(length(unique(Udder_quarter))==1 & is.na(new_column), 
                           "same quarter", 
                           ifelse(length(unique(Udder_quarter))>1,
                                  "different quarter",
                                  new_column))) %>%
  data.frame()
```

**Output is:**

```
  AnimalID Parity Udder_quarter        new_column
1       10      8            LH      same quarter
2       10      8            LH      same quarter
3       10      9            RH      same quarter
4       10      9            RH      same quarter
5       12      4            LH different quarter
6       12      4            RH different quarter
7       12      4            LF different quarter
8       12      4            RF different quarter
9       14      2            RF       one quarter
```

**Sample data:**

```
quarters <- structure(list(AnimalID = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 12, 14
), Parity = c(8, 8, 9, 9, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2), Udder_quarter = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("LF", "LH", "RF", 
"RH"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("AnimalID", "Parity", "Udder_quarter"
), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you very much . It works fine with your example. I can see that the sample data was converted to list, but I don't understand why  (Sorry, new to r). When I run with my actual data it does not recognise the AnimalID. My actual dataset is 2000 rows long so I'm not sure how to get it to the format required.

Comment: Sample data in my answer is not a list but the output of `dput(quarters)`. If you could provide me `dput(head(your_data_frame))` then I will be in a better position to debug the issue which you are facing currently.

Comment: I have dput, but its too long for comment box?

Comment: I meant that you should add the output of `dput(head(quarters))` not `dput(quarters)`

Comment: I got it now! Columns are names slightly different: AnimalID=HerdAnimalID, Udder_quarter=QRT

Answer (score 0):

I would use `ave` to do that:

```
f <- function(x) {
  if (length(x)==1) return("one")
  else if (all(x == x[1])) return("same")
  else return("different")
}

ave(Udder_quarter, interaction(AnimalID, Parity), FUN=f)

# [1] "same"      "same"      "same"      "same"      "different"
# [6] "different" "different" "different" "one"
```